# Add Button inside a TextureView (Android/Java)

Tags: java, android, button, android-camera, textureview

I searched for this and I didn't find any good result for my application.

I am using a TextureView to stream the Camera Preview, and I would like to add a button inside this TextureView, so the button is placed on top of the camera preview. Just like Snapchat does.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I tried to insert the TextureView inside a FrameLayout and it worked.

```
 <RelativeLayout
 ..........
     <FrameLayout
           <TextureView>
     </FrameLayout>

     <Button>

 </RelativeLayout>
```